# Possible to defer parsing of script when using a template?

Tags: javascript, loading, squarespace, gtmetrix

I am using a template on squarespace to build my website and use a lot of custom CSS.

All pages I analyze using GT Metrix get a rating of "C" for speed because of that one issue with `defer parsing of script`. If I'm using a template do I have any control over this? I would assume squarespace provides templates that are optimized so it must be something I've added.

If it helps this is the js that, if deferred, could save 900Kib:

https://assets.squarespace.com/universal/scripts-compressed/common-4dd8f80a39abb8e9e5ab9-min.en-US.js

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

The "common js" file as it is often referred to by Squarespace developers is not something you can easily control.

It requires you to be using a "Squarespace 7" template ([not Squarespace 7.1](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035290252-Squarespace-version-7-1-vs-version-7-0)). Then you must A) [enable developer mode](https://developers.squarespace.com/quick-start) (and accept the ramifications of that) and B) remove `{squarespace-headers}` in the JSON-T and break it down into its various components (because that one line includes dozens of various Squarespace-specific scripts, etc.) and then C) manage the loading of those scripts from then on, updating as necessary if Squarespace updates the platform, script locations, etc. (and they don't announce such changes).

If you're willing and able to do that, you can add `defer` and have full control over the loading of your site. But it is a large undertaking initially and will need to be maintained going forward.

Regarding *"I would assume squarespace provides templates that are optimized so it must be something I've added."*: That's a reasonable assumption, but incorrect. Among experienced Squarespace developers, Squarespace is known to not be well optimized according to, for example, [Google's PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=squarespace.com). I've not used GT Metrix, but it sounds like your experience is similar. This has been an issue with Squarespace for over 5 years. It's unclear if "7.1" will make drastic improvements on this front in the short term.

Answer (score -1):

GT Metrix has a good guide of [how to defer your parsing here.](https://gtmetrix.com/defer-parsing-of-javascript.html)

Basically you just want to rewrite your javascript file to have less javascript in it, either by A) removing unnecessary code, or B) deferring some if that can be loaded later, after page load. Ask yourself, how much of my javascript do I need just to load the page?

I don't use squarespace but [this looks like an example](https://forum.squarespace.com/topic/9648-where-do-i-upload-javascript-files/) of how to upload js files there.